# Constructor parameters C++ const and &

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I can't get the parameters of the constructor right. It's keep poping the same error over and over. The arguments of the class can't be changed i can only change the constructor.

Error C2789 'Aluno::numero': an object of const-qualified type must be initialized

Error C2530 'Aluno::escola': references must be initialized

```
class Aluno {
    string nome;
    string& escola;
    const int numero;
public:
    Aluno(string nome, string escola, int numero){
        this->nome = nome;
        this->escola = escola;
        this->numero = numero;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Aluno * a = new Aluno("aaa", "bbb", 123);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is `escola` a reference? You would, typically, initialize those in constructor initializer list, but if you can't change the arguments of the constructor - that would, at best, bind to local variable, which would lead to UB, when trying to use it.

Comment: Google "member initializer list".

Comment: @SergeyA I would welcome constructive criticism of my answer if you find it bad.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I do not see how it answers OP questions. Granted, OPs question possibly can not be answered, but than one should just refrain from answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `const` members, you need to use an initializer list:

```
Aluno(string nome, string escola, int numero)
    : numero(numero) {
    // ...
}
```

You also need to initialize references in the same way, but this requires passing a reference as the parameter:

```
Aluno(string nome, string& escola, int numero)
    : escola(escola), numero(numero) {
    // ...
}
```

Even though it isn't required by the compiler, initializing `nome` in the same way is more efficient.

```
Aluno(string nome, string& escola, int numero)
    : nome(nome), escola(escola), numero(numero) {
}
```

Comment: This would lead to UB, upon the use of `escola`, due to it being a dangling reference.

Comment: Another example of UB-peddling.

Comment: After the edit this doesn't fix the compiler error the OP is getting.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius The edit you referred to fixed the first compiler error. My most recent edit should address the other error.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice However, the OP stated that they can't change the constructor arguments.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Thanks for your feedback. How would you suggest doing this within the constraints given by the OP?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice So that `escola` wouldn't be a reference, in the first place. That wouldn't involve changing a constructor at all.

Answer (score 4):

Class members that are `const` or references MUST be initialized in a constructor's **member initialization list**, eg:

```
class Aluno
{
    string nome;
    string& escola;
    const int numero;
public:
    Aluno(string nome, string &escola, int numero)
        : nome(nome), escola(escola), numero(numero)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    string b = "bbb";
    Aluno * a = new Aluno("aaa", b, 123);
    delete a; 
    return 0;
}
```

However, notice that I had to change your `escola` input parameter.  You are passing that parameter **by value**, but are trying to store a reference to it. The `escola` class member would be bound to a `string` object that is local to the constructor and goes out of scope when the constructor exits, leaving the reference dangling. You don't want that.

So, either the `escola` input parameter must be changed to a reference as well, as shown above, or else the `escola` class member can't be declared as a reference anymore, eg:

```
class Aluno
{
    string nome;
    string escola;
    const int numero;
public:
    Aluno(string nome, string escola, int numero)
        : nome(nome), escola(escola), numero(numero)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    Aluno * a = new Aluno("aaa", "bbb", 123);
    delete a; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would involve changing the constructor arguments: OP stated that they are not allowed to do so.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I know, but the requirement doesn't make sense, it would cause undefined behavior, so something has to be changed.

Comment: "MUST be initialized in a constructor's member initialization list" - not entirely correct. Using a [default member initializer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) is also ok.

Answer (score 1):

To *initialize* members you need to use either in-class initialization or the constructor initialization list. *Not* the constructor body.

In the constructor body you may re-assign values to members, but at that point they have already been default initialized (unless you explicitly initialized them in-class or by using the initialization list) and not all types can be default initialized (like references).

Answer (score -1):

`escola` is a reference, so it needs to be initialized in the field initialization list as it's being allocated. The same is true for your const `numero`:

```
Aluno(string nome, string escola, int numero) : 
    nome(nome), escola(escola), numero(numero) { }
```

However, this would result in UB since the parameter `escola` that your member `escola` is referencing will go out of scope. As such, the parameter must also be a reference:

```
Aluno(string nome, string &escola, int numero) : 
    nome(nome), escola(escola), numero(numero) { }
```

Comment: But what is it referring *to*?

Comment: This would lead to UB, upon the use of `escola`, due to it being a dangling reference.

Comment: This will fix compilation error (possibly), but would be UB.

Comment: @scohe001 OP stated that they can't change the constructor arguments.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I think the OP was referring to the class members